# How to .write() two items, a zero and an iterator in Python?

Tags: python, csv, formatting, conditional-statements

I may have a simple formatting question here - I would like to do something like hrOut.write('0',i) in order to add/preface a zero to 'i' which is a timestamp, but I don't know the correct syntax. My code is below. Thank you all.

```
hrIn = open('HrsInput.csv')
hrOut = open('HrsOutput.csv', 'wt')

for i in hrIn:
    if len(i) < 5:    
        hrOut.write('0', i)
    else:
        hrOut.write(i)

hrIn.close()
hrOut.close()
```

** I eventually found that the padding technique works. I may have been tricked by excel because in notepad the padding shows up.

```
hrIn = open('HrsInput.csv')
hrOut = open('HrsOutput.csv', 'wt')

for i in hrIn:   
    hrOut.write("{}\n".format(i.rstrip().zfill(5)))

hrIn.close()
hrOut.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use str.format:

```
hrOut.write('0{}'.format(i))
```

Or remove the if/else and pad:

```
for i in hrIn:   
    hrOut.write("{}\n".format(i.rstrip().zfill(5)))
```

zfill will only add a zero for your times with four characters:

```
In [21]: "12:33".zfill(5)
Out[21]: '12:33'

In [22]: "2:33".zfill(5)
Out[22]: '02:33'
```

Comment: Thanks, that eliminates my syntax error, but I may have another problem. I'm not seeing the zeros being added. I should explain a little more- I have hourly timestamps that either have X:XX or XX:XX. So, XX:XX is already correct, but I'm trying to add a zero to the front of X:XX making it XX:XX. Does your suggestion snippet do this or am I not handling this correctly?

Comment: I'm not too sure if the input is in string form. I'm looking at the input column in excel, and it doesn't seem to have a format defined. If I define as text, I lose the X:XX or XX:XX format. If I just .write(i) I get the same formatting in the out file as the in file.

Comment: @AF2k15, zfill will add a leading zero if the string is four chars long, are you counting the newline?

Comment: I tried both techniques with two different code editors and deleted the out file from my previous tries each time to make sure it's not an overwriting issue. I'll have to assume there's something wrong with my input file and not the code, so I appreciate your information. Thanks.

Comment: @AF2k15, no worries, I added a couple of examples to show that it does actually work!

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion . How about doing something like as follows .

(1) Split the timestamp on ':' . For example :

```
"1:20".split(':')[:1]
```

This will return 1

(2) Then use zfill or the sprintf equivalent in python . Something like :

```
"%02d" % (1,)

or use zfill on the split string (1) like : 

"1".zfill(3)
```